# Understanding undelimited continuations

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, continuations

Suppose, I have the following code (in C-like syntax):

```
void foo(int arg) { ... }

int bar() {
...
// call with continuation 
...
}

foo ( bar() )
// after foo invocation
```

1) Function `foo` invokes function `bar`, which is running until it reaches the line with `call with continuation`.

2) At this line a `continuation` function is created. It represents the rest of `bar` and `foo`. The `continuation` function is passed as an argument to `call with continuation` function.

3) The `call with continuation` function does whatever it wants with the argument (e.g. it may just store in a global variable) and returns.

4) Once the `call with continuation` returns we immediately jump to the line with "after foo invocation" and the rest of `bar` and `foo` are not executed.

5) In order to continue execution of `bar` and `foo` we should explicitly invoke the `continuation` function (created in (2) and probably stored in (3)). Once the `continuation` function is invoked the execution continues immediately after the `call with continuation`.

Is it correct? Am I missing something about undelimited continuations?

Comment: The behaviour you describe (step 4 - the rest of bar and foo are not executed) only makes sense if you can choose a point up to which you want to skip execution. This would make it *delimited* continuations. However, in common delimited continuation APIs like `reset`/`shift`, invoking a continuation behaves like a function call, instead of a jump, because after such a continuation finishes, it returns to the code that invoked it.

Answer (score 5):

No. Typically, undelimited continuations (eg created with Scheme's `call/cc`) jump when you invoke the `continuation`, not when you call `call/cc` (aka `call-with-current-continuation`).

So, fleshing out your example:

```
continuation savedk;

void foo(int arg) { ... }

int bar() {
  ...
  call/cc(handler)
  // after call/cc
  println "after call/cc"
  ...
}

void handler(continuation k) {
  savedk = k
}

foo ( bar() )
// after foo invocation
```

1. Execution starts. We enter `bar` (we haven't entered `foo` yet; we'll do that when we get done with `bar`).
2. When we hit the call to `call/cc` in `bar`, the "program context" is turned into an object called a continuation. At this point, the program context consists of "finish executing `bar`, then call `foo` on the result, and then do whatever comes after the `foo` invocation". The continuation is passed to the function given as an argument to `call/cc`, which is `handler` in my example above.
3. `handler` does something with the continuation. Let's assume it stores it in a global variable. Then it returns to the point right after the `call/cc` call, still inside of `bar`.
4. Let's say we print something out at this point. Then `bar` finishes and we call `foo`, and it finishes.
5. If we now apply the continuation in `savedk`, control jumps back into `bar` and restores the program context to "finish executing `bar`, then call `foo` on the result, and then do whatever comes after the `foo` invocation". So we get another line printed. In fact, if we don't clear the `savedk` variable or test some other state, we might get an infinite loop if "do whatever comes after the `foo` invocation" is call `savedk` again!